# Understanding this code, adding data into a database

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse

So I followed this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/Createdeleteupdate.htm) and I understand everything except:

```
// ---add a contact---
db.open();
long id = db.insertContact("Wei-Meng Lee", "weimenglee@learn2develop.net");
id = db.insertContact("Mary Jackson", "mary@jackson.com");
db.close();
```

I know it's purpose is to add a new contact, but how does this work? It seems as if it's adding 2 contacts at the same time. How do I make it add only 1 contact at a time?

Comment: Looks as if it's adding two contacts one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure if I understand problem...

```
db.open();
long id = db.insertContact("Wei-Meng Lee",
    "weimenglee@learn2develop.net");
///id = db.insertContact("Mary Jackson", "mary@jackson.com");
db.close();
```

Now you adding only one contact.

Comment: Hmm, but then why is it making a new variable (id) in order to execute the db.insertContact

Comment: If you just want to add contact to database you dont need `long id`. New variable (id) is if you want to add this contact one more time or do something else with it. Remove `long id` and that should work

Comment: If mine explanation satisfy you, click accept

Answer (score 0):

This would add only one contact (with the name "Wei-Meng Lee" and the specified e-mail address):

```
// ---add a contact---
db.open();
long id = db.insertContact("Wei-Meng Lee",
    "weimenglee@learn2develop.net");
db.close();
```

In the code, two contacts are added, as two `insertContacts` calls are executed.
The `insertContact` method returns the id of the just-inserted contact, which is stored in the `id` variable.